# Como eu elimino a primeira variável para fazer testes com a variável t-1?

Tags: r

Importo os arquivos do Excel mas não consigo defasar a varíavel no R. A função lag ela elimina a primeira observação e não consigo usar a nrow ou algo parecido. Como eu faria? Queria usar para fazer o teste de Berenblutt-Webb

Comment: Bota o código que você utilizou para ler a planilha?

Answer (score 1):

Tente a função `lag` do pacote `dplyr`. Ela possui um argumento `default` que pode ser usado para completar os valores anteriores. No caso usei `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  dia = seq(from = as.Date("2017-01-01"), length.out = 100, by = 1),
  x = 1:100
)


df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    x_lag = lag(x, n = 1, default = NA)
  )

head(df)


         dia x x_lag
1 2017-01-01 1    NA
2 2017-01-02 2     1
3 2017-01-03 3     2
4 2017-01-04 4     3
5 2017-01-05 5     4
6 2017-01-06 6     5
```